# JAXB Unmarshalling to two different objects from same XML

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

During the process of unmarshalling using JAXB, I'm trying to unmarshall file.xml to 2 different java pojo, but the unmarshaller keeps thinking that the second object is still the first one so it gets a cast class error.

AS you can see in the following code I try to unmarshall

```
this.timbre = (TimbreFiscalDigital) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(path.toFile());
this.comprobante = (Comprobante) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(path.toFile());
```

It always get an error telling that there is a class cast exception

> java.lang.ClassCastException: cfdi.bindings.CFDI32.Comprobante cannot
>   be cast to cfdi.bindings.TimbreFiscal.TimbreFiscalDigital

If I only try to unmarshall to "Comprobante" it works... but not for "TimbreFiscalDigital"

```
public CFDI(Path path){

     JAXBContext jaxbContext;
    try {
        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("cfdi.bindings.CFDI32:cfdi.bindings.TimbreFiscal");
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

        this.timbre = (TimbreFiscalDigital) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(path.toFile());
        this.comprobante = (Comprobante) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(path.toFile());

    } catch (JAXBException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CFDI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }    

}
```

I cant find the error... FYI I'm using netbeans 8.1 JAXB

**UPDATE** Sample XML from comment:

```
<Comprobante>
    <Emisor></Emisor>
    <Complemento>
        <TimbreFiscalDigital>
        </TimbreFiscalDigital>
    </Complemento>
</Comprobante>
```

Comment: Well, if your XML contains a `<Comprobante>` element, why do you think it should unmarshall into a `TimbreFiscalDigital` class? The Unmarshaller will unmarchall into the class that is *bound* to the element type found in the XML data.

Comment: Hi @Andreas, the XML is a <Comprobante> and has a TimbreFiscal in the same XML, something like this: <Comprobante>
 <Emisor></Emisor>
 <Complemento>
  <TimbreFiscalDigital>
  </TimbreFiscalDigital>
 </Complemento>
</Comprobante>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your XML contains a `<Comprobante>` root element, the XML will be unmarshalled to an instance of the `Comprobante` class. The `<Complemento>` and `<TimbreFiscalDigital>` nested elements will be unmarshalled to nested objects of the `Comprobante` class.

Not knowing your schema, I'm going to assume that `<Complemento>` maps to a `List<TimbreFiscalDigital> complemento` field of the `Comprobante` class. To get the instance of `TimbreFiscalDigital`, you would have to ask the instance of `Comprobante` for that list and iterate the list.

You can't do it by parsing the XML again. The full XML has already been parsed.